# How do I get a new copy of amsart?

Tags: installing, mactex, mac, amsart

According to the comments and answers to [*Why is LaTeX replacing 2010 for the math subject classification with 1991?*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94745/why-is-latex-replacing-2010-for-the-math-subject-classification-with-1991), using an old copy of amsart results in a 1991 Mathematics Subject Classification, rather than a 2010 Mathematics Subject Classification.

My question is: Where do I get a new copy of amsart, and how does one install it on OS X? (I already have MacTeX installed.)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I personally would recommend you download the complete TeXLive2014 instead of trying to update one file at a time. For the Mac you can download it from [MacTeX-2014 Distribution](https://www.tug.org/mactex/).

Comment: `amsart` is available [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amslatex/amscls). (Read the installation instructions to find out how to generate the .cls file.)

Comment: @PeterGrill Depending on the age of the Mac, it may not be possible to update MacTeX.

Comment: another way to get the current `amsart` is to download the `amscls` distribution from http://www.ams.org/tex/amslatex.  this distribution already has the `.cls` files "unpacked".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it's not really clear what the problem is here.

`amsart` was updated in 2009 to accept an option

```
\subjclass[2010]{...}
```

there is a large backlog of existing documents that use earlier versions of the
subject classification, so versions later than 1991 must be specified as options.

if a new version of `amsart` is really needed, there are several ways to get it;
it is part of the `amscls` package:

- it is included in tex live
- it can be retrieved
  [from ctan](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amslatex/amscls)
- it can be downloaded [from the ams server](http://www.ams.org/tex/amslatex)